# Is the use of the adjective "pedantic" always derogatory?

Tags: connotations

The adjective "pedantic" is sometimes used derogatorily. Can it be used in a neutral or positive context?

In other words, if person A refers person B as pedantic, can it sometimes be used as a neutral or positive description? Or is the use of the adjective "pedantic" always derogatory?

Comment: Ages ago, pedant meant only _schoolteacher_...

Comment: @P.E.Dant Is that how you're using it?

Comment: @AlanCarmack My use is ironic, or purports to be, at least, in spite of many failures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can only be used in a derogatory fashion, and I think the best way to demonstrate this is by comparing the definitions of "pedant" from a number of dictionaries:

> [**Merriam-Webster**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant)
>   **Simple Definition:**
>   A person who annoys other people by correcting small errors and giving 
>   too much attention to minor details.
>
> **Full Definition:**
>   One who makes a show of knowledge;
>   One who is unimaginative or who unduly emphasizes minutiae in the
>   presentation or use of knowledge;
>   A formalist or precisionist in teaching.
>
> [**Cambridge Dictionary**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pedant)
>   *Disapproving*
>   A person who is too interested in formal rules and small details that are
>   not important.
>
> [**Oxford Dictionaries**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedant)
>   A person who is excessively concerned with minor details and rules or
>   with displaying academic learning.
>
> [**Macmillan Dictionary**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pedant)
>   Someone who gives too much important to details and formal rules, especially
>   of grammar.
>
> [**Collins Dictionary**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pedant)
>   A person who relies too much on academic learning or who is concerned
>   chiefly with insignificant detail.

In each of these definitions, there is some mention of excess, arrogance, or annoyance. None of these are positive traits or qualities.

---

If I wanted to describe someone who always aimed to do the correct thing, *pedant* would not be my word of choice. I would probably choose one of (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**meticulous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meticulous)
>   Showing great attention to detail; very careful and precise:
>   "*the designs are hand-glazed with meticulous care*"
>   "*he had always been so meticulous about his appearance*"
>
> [**thorough**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/thorough)
>   Performed or written with great care and completeness:
>   "*officers have made a thorough examination of the wreckage*"
>
> Taking pains to do something carefully and completely:
>   "*the British authorities are very thorough*"
>
> [**rigorous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rigorous)
>   Extremely thorough and careful:
>   "*the rigorous testing of consumer products*"
>
> (Of a person) adhering strictly to a belief or system:
>   "*a rigorous teetotaller*"
>
> [**scholarly**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/scholarly)
>   Involving or relating to serious academic study:
>   "*scholarly journals*"
>   "*a scholarly career*"
>
> Having or showing knowledge, learning, or devotion of academic pursuits:
>   "*a scholarly account of the period*"
>   "*an earnest, scholarly man*"

My exact choice would depend on the message I was trying to put across, since the meanings are all slightly different.

Answer (score 3):

Let me quote a Richard Rubenstein, a lawyer who studied at Albany Law School:

> To be pedantic, one must be overly concerned with minor details and tend to intentionally display academic learning.

Successful lawyers both pay close attention to details, in a positive sense (the details are often what got their clients into trouble in the first place) and display academic mastery of the law in an understandable, practical way. The law is a tool, not a flag or symbol. Bad lawyers obfuscate. Good ones clarify and illuminate, both in writing and in speech.

So, someone who lacks the depth to pay attention to details and who is intimidated by mastery of a subject might call a lawyer simply doing his or her job “pedantic.” That often says more about the commentator than the subject.

Answer (score 1):

LMS has given an excellent answer that covers serious writing and conversation.

I can just conceive of a friendly situation where I might turn to someone in the group and say "we need to get this right; what does our resident pedant think?" The "resident" or other such affectionate modifier (I hope) ameliorating the negative "pedant".

Comment: I think this is, as non-pedants like to say, the exception that proves the rule. This sounds like a joking context to me, so "pedant" is still chosen because it is derogatory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedantic addressed exactly this question: pedantic is almost always an insult.

> #### What is the difference between *pedantic* and *didactic*?
>
> The word *didactic* generally means "designed to teach," but it is [often used in a negative way](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/didactic-vs-pedantic) to describe boring or annoying lessons, or the people who teach them. While *didactic* can have a neutral meaning, **pedantic is almost always an insult**. It typically describes an irritating person who is eager to correct small errors others make, or who wants everyone to know just how much of an expert they are, especially in some narrow or boring subject matter.
>
> #### Is *pedantic* an insult?
>
> *Pedantic* is an insulting word used to describe someone who annoys others by correcting small errors, caring too much about minor details, or emphasizing their own expertise especially in some narrow or boring subject matter.